# Get-ChildItem "REGISTRY::$path" is locking my registry hive

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi, registry

I'm using the unmanaged Windows API [RegLoadKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regloadkeya) within PowerShell to mount registry hives offline.

That works fine, and outside of PowerShell everything works as expected - once mounted I can browse to them in regedit.exe, and manipulate them and so on.

However, if I use Get-ChildItem I can then no longer dismount the hive. RegUnloadKey returns a value of 5 which is "Access Denied". This does NOT happen if I simply don't touch the registry key from within PowerShell

The code is very very simply, I can replicate it as such:

```
Add-Type -Name LoadHive -NameSpace RegistryHelper -MemberDefinition @"

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Int32 RegLoadKey(UInt32 hKey, String lpSubKey, String lpFile);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Int32 RegUnLoadKey(UInt32 hKey, string lpSubKey);

"@

$hiveMountPoint = 2147483651 (This is the built-in constant for HKEY_USERS)
$hiveMountName = "TEMP-HIVE"
$hivePath = [Filepath to offline hive]
[RegistryHelper.LoadHive]::RegLoadKey($hiveMountPoint, $hiveMountName, $hivePath)

$hiveKeys = Get-ChildItem "REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\TEMP-HIVE" 

[RegistryHelper.LoadHive]::RegUnLoadKey($hiveMountPoint, $hiveMountName)
```

I'm using [RegUnLoadKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regunloadkeya) to dismount. Can anybody shed some light on why Get-ChildItem is locking me out here?

Comment: There must be no open keys in the hive to be unloaded. otherwise `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE` will be returned. and this status converted to "Access Denied"

Comment: @RbMm Sounds about right, but how I close the keys and why is PowerShell holding them open?

Comment: *Sounds about right* in sense ? error is `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE`. *why is PowerShell holding them open* this is question faster about PowerShell  then winapi. if you not direct by self call api

Comment: @RbMm I know, I'm happy it's fundamentally a PowerShell issue/query. But I need to fix it - I don't know what you're trying to say

Comment: yes, powershell holds sub keys opened even after execute `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: think this can not be fixed. only exit powershell. bug/resource leaks in powershell

Comment: @RbMm Ah, I should have added that - exiting the PowerShell session doesn't resolve it. Only a reboot seems to!

Comment: dont know. i load hive with regedit ui. after i execute *Get-ChildItem "REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\0"* ( i load under name *0*) - i can not unload hive 0 from regedit - error. but after i exit powershell - hive unloaded ok

Answer (score 1):

`Get-ChildItem` is agnostic to the underlying provider (FileSystem, Registry ...). So even if you use `Interop` to load the hive, Powershell is not aware of that and the [`Registry Provider`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/namespaces/RegistryProvider.cs) will return [`RegistryKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=net-6.0) objects. These objects contains a `Handle` property that probably prevent you to close the hive gracefully. You should call [`Close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.close?view=net-6.0) method on all keys stored in `$hiveKeys` before unloading the hive to close all handles.